# How to split rows into columns in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe (with dimension 840rows x 1columns):

```
0   151284 Apr 19 11:37 0-01-20200419063614
1   48054 Apr 21 12:50 0-01-20200421074934
2   187588 Apr 21 13:55 0-01-20200421085439
3   51584 Apr 21 14:37 0-01-20200421143636
4   63522 Apr 22 08:40 0-01-20200422083937
```

I want to convert this dataframe into a format like this:

```
id      datetime             size 
151284  2020-04-19 11:37:00  0-01-20200419063614
 .        .           .
```

datetime being in the format: `(yyyy-mm-dd)(hr-min-sec)`. So basically splitting a single column into three columns and also combining date and time into a single `datetime` column in a standard format.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: output of `df.columns`: `Index(['col'], dtype='object')`

Comment: What will be the values is `size` column here?

Comment: @mayank-porwal  thanks! I just edited the question and mentioned the detailed format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [70]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['151284 Apr 19 11:37 0-01-20200419063614', '48054 Apr 21 12:50 0-01-20200421074934', '187588 Apr 21 13:55 0-01-20200421085439', '51584 Apr 21 14:37 0-01-20200421143636',
    ...: '63522 Apr 22 08:40 0-01-20200422083937']})

In [54]: df['id'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[0]
In [55]: df['Datetime'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[1] + ' ' + df.col.str.split(' ').str[2] + ' ' + df.col.str.split(' ').str[3]
In [57]: df['Size'] = df.col.str.split(' ').str[-1]

In [63]: from dateutil import parser
In [65]: def format_datetime(x): 
    ...:     return parser.parse(x) 
    ...:     

In [67]: df['Datetime'] = df.Datetime.apply(format_datetime)
In [79]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[79]: 
       id            Datetime                 Size
0  151284 2020-04-19 11:37:00  0-01-20200419063614
1   48054 2020-04-21 12:50:00  0-01-20200421074934
2  187588 2020-04-21 13:55:00  0-01-20200421085439
3   51584 2020-04-21 14:37:00  0-01-20200421143636
4   63522 2020-04-22 08:40:00  0-01-20200422083937
```

Comment: What is the output of your `df.columns`?

Comment: No. In my df, column named `col` is the one which we need to split into 3 columns. I am asking for the same column name in your df. Please paste the output of `df.columns` when you just create this df from `csv`.

Comment: Ok, please check. I did the same exact thing and it works fine for me. There must be something missed somewhere.